# Standard ODBC connection string parseing with special characters

Tags: odbc

Based on [ODBS standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqldriverconnect-function?view=sql-server-ver16), special characters are allowed in strings provided they are braced in `{` `}`. It is IMO difficult to clarify all aspects from the standard(see comments below [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73086343/805896))

This is a *what to do question* rather than *how to do*: Is a key-values like `PWD={Iam};password};` considered a **valid** case? Should the *value* be expected to parse to `Iam};password` ?

Once this is answered, one can look at more exotic cases like:

- `PWD={Iam};password}  ;`
- `PWD={I am }; a password};`
- `PWD={I am } ; a    password};`

Comment: Can you show what you have and add relevant tags so people will find this question?

Comment: "Is a key-values like PWD={Iam};password}; considered a valid case?" - nobody knows. The linked page says ["Avoid using embedded braces in a keyword value."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/syntax/sqldriverconnect-function?view=sql-server-ver16#:~:text=Avoid%20using%20embedded%20braces%20in%20a%20keyword%20value) but then it *also* says "A DSN or connection string value enclosed with braces ({}) containing any of the characters []{}(),;?*=!@ is passed intact to the driver" - this implies that somehow the `}` in `};` or at the end of the input is more special...

Comment: I would make my own safe assumptions here instead **OR** look for more authoritative standard specification (which might be paid).